# How to force reload the website with Flask

Tags: python, flask

When a specific event happens, I store several data and want an alert to happen. When I do it right now with

```
return flask.redirect("the_same_url")
```

it loads the alert in the source code but it doesn't really alert. But when I refresh it manually it does show the alert. Is there a way to force this refresh by flask so the alert appears without me and later users having to manually refresh it?

Comment: Not really, either the client needs some javascript to regularly poll the server if there is a alert yet or you need some kind of websocket or HTTP PUSH connection set up to allow sending messages to the client Javascript that it can then use to decide to reload the page.

Comment: @mousetail maybe I can do it with JavaScript... let's see

Already thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah,
basically I used the JavaScript feature `document.location.reload()` together with a

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

This isn't Flask but I could use it.